# how to enable Rule to StringReplace

Tags: string-manipulation

this is a not workable code to test whether bracket is legal:

```
("(({{[[]]}})" //. {"{}" -> "", "[]" -> "", "()" -> ""}) == ""
```

I want to know that how to make [`Rule`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) have the same effect as [`StringReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringReplace.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about doing this instead of adapting `RepaceRepeated`:

```
FixedPoint[
  StringReplace[{"{}" -> "", "[]" -> "", "()" -> ""}]
, "(({{[[]]}})"
] === ""
```